# Ladder if else with multiple statements in each

Tags: r

I want to do this ladder if else with multiple statements within each condition, however, it runs to the two following errors: 
`Error: unexpected symbol in:` and 
`Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`. 
It seems that it is not possible to have more than one statement within each condition, but shouldn't be the case. right?

```
if (condition 1){
  results[i,3] <- 1 
  results[i,4] <- 1 
} 
  else if (condition 2){
    results[i,1] <- 1 
    results[i,2] <- 1
  }
else 
  results[i,1:4] <- 0
```

Comment: Looks possible to me. In R the `if` and `for` statements are flow-control operators, so any assignments are done in the environment from which they are called (unlike what happens in most functions). What problems are you facing? Pose a dataset that illustrates the issues, I think best practice would use curly-braces after each `else` for clarity if code and better error messages.

Comment: That error sounds a lot like poor syntax. Did you forget the curly brackets after the last `else` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way R works is that it reads a line, iterpretes it, executes it if possible, reads next line

After in this snippet

```
if (condition 1){
  results[i,3] <- 1 
  results[i,4] <- 1 
}
```

the last line is read, R thinks that the if body is finished and executes it.
Afterwards it reads `else` and cannot put the `else` in an context with an `if` (because that was already processed)

What you instead want is to do is put a `else` in the same line as the closed curly brackets so that R knows it needs to read further before execution.

```
if (condition 1){

  results[i,3] <- 1 
  results[i,4] <- 1 

} else if (condition 2){

    results[i,1] <- 1 
    results[i,2] <- 1

} else {

  results[i,1:4] <- 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, and the former didn't work because `else` started at a new line, not immediately after closing curly bracket.

```
 if (condition 1){
      results[i,3] <- 1 
      results[i,4] <- 1
      } else if (condition 2){
        results[i,1] <- 1 
        results[i,2] <- 1
      } else {
          results[i,1:4] <- 0 
      }
```